# Convert RTF Stream to Plain Text Stream

Tags: text, crystal-reports, stream, rtf

I have crystal report and I need to convert it to text file. Currently I can only convert it to RTF Stream. Now I need to convert the RTF Stream to Text Stream. I am using C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but you are using the [ExportToStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225995.aspx) method with [ExportFormatType.RichText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226443.aspx):

```
Stream stream = report.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.RichText);
```

This exports the report into an RTF stream. Now you wish to convert this stream to plain text (extract the text from the RTF). If that's true then [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346/how-do-i-extract-insert-text-into-rtf-string-in-c) might have the answer for you.