# rtf convert to text

Tags: c#, ios, rtf

I created C# window program.
I want to display RTF contents made by Window Program in ipad app  .

In addition, I want to display contents made by ipad in RTF textbox of window program ,too.

Is this possible? 
Please advice to me. thanks!

Comment: See related ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419544/convert-rtf-stream-to-plain-text-stream?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UIWebview` to display `RTF files

```
NSURL *url = <URL FOR YOUR SAVED RTF DOCUMENT IN THE TMP/CACHES FOLDER>;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```

where `webview` is an iVar that is a `UIWebView`