# Loading rtf file to string to manipulate in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, ms-word, rtf

Is there a way to read rtf files into a string and then replace some patterns on them?
Ideally I would want to save the new string into an rtf file again and open from wordpad.
All I see is the richtextbox solution which i would like to skip.

I used to do that with, Microsoft.Office.Interop, by creating `Word.Application` then `Word.Document` then `oDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="[[Blah Blah]]", ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)` but I realize that Word might not always be installed on client...

Comment: Why do you want to skip the RichTextBox solution?

Comment: Do you want to edit the RTF text manual (e.g., in a TextBox) or programatically using code (e.g., File.ReadAllText, string.Replace, File.WriteAllText)?

Comment: There is no point using RichTextBox, because I don't want to give the user the possibility to write or change anything...

Comment: I just want to programmatically find and replace some specific text sequences like [[Blah]] with something like 1233...

Answer (score 1):

Microsofts suggests using the RichTextBox control as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488002.aspx). This seems to be used by other members as mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450/cleaning-up-rtf-text).

However, there are some other solutions such as [NRTFTree](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11306/NRTFTree-A-class-library-for-RTF-processing-in-C).